# What happens if you want to type a list() but python thinks it is a function?

Tags: python

So in my code there is a list called `l`. I then typed `l(b) = l(b), X(a)`. That was supposed to make the item `b` in `l` turn into item `b` in `l` joined with the letter `a` in `X`. But python thinks `l(b)` is a function. It thinks `b` is the parameter and `l` is the function name. How do I fix it?

Switching the sides.

```
a = 0
b = 0
l = list()
while a <= len(X):
  while not X(a)==' ':
    l(b) = l(b),X(a)
  l.append()
  b = b + 1
```

Comment: Both these loops are infinite because neither `a` nor `X` change at any point.

Comment: `X` is not defined in your example code

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python list reference", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  This should be in the materials from which you learned about lists.
Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: A comma in an expression creates a tuple, it doesn't join

Answer (score 2):

To get element `b` in list `l`, use brackets `[]` instead of parens `()`.

So that means `l[b]`, not `l(b)`.